# Can anybody rephrase "it may not feel like it" in this context for me, please?

Tags: meaning-in-context

With major economies like Germany and Japan offering negative yields on their, for example, ten year bonds, the Federal Reserve Bank (the Fed) has to walk a delicate line. Other countries are keeping their rates low in an effort to stimulate their slow-growth economies. And while **it may not feel like it** to millions of Americans who are financially struggling, the U.S. economy is one of the strongest in the world.  So the Fed is under pressure to actually raise our interest rates to slow down our economy, offset the future threat of inflation, and restore a more normal term structure of interest rates.

source: [www.forbes.com](http://www.forbes.com/forbes/welcome/?toURL=http://www.forbes.com/sites/markavallone/2016/09/10/are-low-interest-rates-hurting-or-helping-you/&refURL=https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/103441/can-anybody-rephrase-it-may-not-feel-like-it-in-this-context-for-me-please&referrer=https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/103441/can-anybody-rephrase-it-may-not-feel-like-it-in-this-context-for-me-please#3b5c1af760e7)

Comment: Note the idiomatic expression "*to feel like*" : http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/feel-like-something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not feel like it, that is, it may appear different from what it really is. Millions of Americans don't feel that the economy is actually stronger than what they think it is:

You may say:

> And despite the fact that it (the economy)  appears to be weak to millions of  Americans....,the US economy is one of the strongest of the word.